# Could not find or load main class Hbase clouera

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I am trying to Run Simple Hbase Java Client Program.

I am doing below to add Jar file to CLASSPATH

```
export classpath=$classpath:'/home/cloudera/workspace/examples/target/examples-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar':.
```

When i do shell `habse classpath`

Its not displaying my Jar file to `habse classpath`, so that i am running into to the below exceptions. Can any on please help

```
[cloudera@quickstart target]$ hbase com.hbase.importer.examples.HbaseStationImporter /user/hbase/data/ncdc/metadata/stations-fixed-width.txt
Error: Could not find or load main class com.hbase.importer.examples.HbaseStationImporter
[cloudera@quickstart target]$
```

Comment: When you say, it is not displaying, do you mean this "echo $CLASSPATH"? And how are you running the program.

Comment: i mean the perticular jar file is not included in the CLASSPATH

Comment: Are you seeing the current path properly, before adding the new path? Try to display the path before adding using "echo $CLASSPATH" and then see it after setting. while exporting, move the $classpath to last and try. Look into this [post](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for more help.